# Magento categories

Tags: php, magento

http://sandbox.jinoh.dk/magento/index.php/

I am sadly a noob with this system. I have a series of (stupid?) questions.

1) If I create a category, I can't seem to find the damn link to it. I don't know how to access the category listing on the front end.

2) I can't get the Layered Navigation to work. :( I HAVE set the parent categories to Is Anchor = Yes. http://sandbox.jinoh.dk/magento/index.php/produkter is a testpage which I set up manually with a block code.Is this why it doesn't show up?

3) Is it possible to get the left navigation to show subcategories - and even when inside them? I didn't manage to get it to work but I have been researching for hours now :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you set Is Active->Yes for the categories you made..?

Comment: you should set category top navigation depth from admin section. `System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Category Top Navigation` set how many sub category you want it to show, ex. 2.

Comment: The categories are active, yes. - And I tried to edit it, Oğuz, but nothing happened.

Comment: Did you create the new categories INSIDE the root category? If so the link should appear in the top menu on the frontend.

Comment: Hi @vinai. I did modify a little in the different settings. Now everything works as I want it except for the Layered Navigation. The categories are inside the root category. There are three levels, Root>Sub>Sub-Sub. How can I make navigation in the sidebar even appear on the Sub and Sub-sub pages? Wouldn't that be possible?

Comment: Maybe try this exxtension? http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vertical-navigation-with-css-classes.html

Comment: I got it to work :) Thanks for your help anyways. It was something in the layout file that made it output wrong things:P (catalog.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. Thank you.

I ended up tweaking with some codes, adding a sidebar manually. Thank you for guiding me the right way, @Vinai